# IllegalStateException: must not be null of Spock unit test with Kotlin business logic

Tags: spring, unit-testing, kotlin, spock

I try to get a `MongoTemplate` (Spring Data) worked with my Spock spec test. I use Kotlin as language for the business logic.

Please see my specification logic:

```
@SpringBootTest
class BookingServiceSpec extends Specification {

    BookingService bookingService;
    BookingEntity bookingEntity
    CustomerEntity customerEntity
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    def setup() {
        bookingEntity = GroovyMock(BookingEntity)
        customerEntity = GroovyMock(CustomerEntity)
        mongoTemplate = Mock()
        bookingService = new BookingService(mongoTemplate)

        customerEntity.getEmail() >> "test@test.com"
        mongoTemplate.find(!null, !null, !null) >> List.of(bookingEntity)
    }

    def "should return a list of bookings if asked for bookings for a customer"() {
        when: "booking service is used to find bookings for a given customer"
        List<BookingEntity> bookings = bookingService.getBookings(customerEntity)
        then: "it should call the find method of the mongo template and return a list of booking entities"
        1 * mongoTemplate.find(!null, !null, !null)
    }
}
```

Running this code throws an `IllegalStateException` with detail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: mongoTemplate.find(query…::class.java, "bookings") must not be null

    at com.nomadsolutions.areavr.booking.BookingService.getBookings(BookingService.kt:22)
    at com.nomadsolutions.areavr.booking.BookingServiceSpec.should return a list of bookings if asked for bookings for a customer(BookingServiceSpec.groovy:37)
```

The entity data classes are defined like this:

```
data class CustomerEntity(val surname: String, val name: String, val email: String)
data class BookingEntity(val customerEntity: CustomerEntity, val date: Date)
```

And here is the business logic:

```
@Service
class BookingService(var mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate) {

    fun addBooking(booking: BookingEntity) {
        mongoTemplate.insert(booking)
    }

    fun getBookings(customerEntity: CustomerEntity): List<BookingEntity> {
        val query = Query()
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("customer.email").`is`(customerEntity.email))
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, BookingEntity::class.java, "bookings")
    }

}
```

I found out that the stubbing for `customerEntity` is not working properly since `customerEntity.email` is returning `null` in the logic while debugging via test run.

I'd love to continue with Spock but it seems to block me from testing fast since I have to care about things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from `setup()` method:

```
    mongoTemplate.find(!null, !null, !null) >> List.of(bookingEntity)
```

And change the interaction test in the `then` section of the test case in this way:

```
then: 'it should call the find method of the mongo template and return a list of booking entities'
1 * mongoTemplate.find(!null, !null, !null) >> [bookingEntity]
```

It is because when you are mocking and stubbing the same method call (`mongoTemplate.find()` in your case) it should happen in the same interaction.

You can read more about that in the [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing).

Comment: Interesting. I'd never came up with that way since I would've thought I need to stub it before the actual call of that stub has to happen. Which in my case would've been in the `when` scope